# Struts2 : Action's property setter is not invoked

Tags: java, struts2, action

I try to post a simple form :

```
<s:form action="register">
<s:textfield name="lastname"></s:textfield>
    <s:submit></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

The action :

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String lastname;
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("register");
    }

    public String getLastname() {
      return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
      this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

The action outputs the register string but the setter is never called.

Why the setter is never called ? 
Even when I type directly the action in the browser `http://localhost:8686/register.action?lastname=sdjh` the setter is not invoked but the `execute` method outputs "register".

Comment: Execute is called by default once you POST. Have you defined a register action? try rename your getters/setters to getLastName and setLastName respectively.

Comment: @NoelMurphy the register action is defined a shown in the post (RegisterAction). Why `getLastName` instead of `getLastname`?

Comment: Stuts2 has naming conventions that follow java, it can't recognize certain getters/setters unless they follow the conventions. Did you define your action in your struts.xml? otherwise it's redirecting to your action class (RegisterAction) and using the execute method. Try renaming your action.

Comment: @NoelMurphy I know. But why the capital letter `N` in the middle ? does the Reflection API check for typos ?

Comment: @paolo parameters are set prior to action execution.

Comment: As shown here the getters and setters would work. Reflection doesn't "check for typos", it just tries to call whatever you've named it. It's not clear what the actual sequence of events is since you didn't include your action configuration.

Comment: @NoelMurphy What would renaming them do? The form name and getter/setters are named consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any missing parts in your code. I tried to replicate the same and I found it's working perfectly. Following is my code.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="register" class="com.tmp.RegisterAction">
            <result>one.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="register">
        <s:textfield name="lastname"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit></s:submit>
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**RegisterAction**

```
    package com.tmp;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


    public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {

        private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

        String                      lastname;


        public String getLastname() {

            return lastname;
        }


        public void setLastname( String lastname ) {

            this.lastname = lastname;
        }


        @Override
        public String execute() throws Exception {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Action.SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

**one.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<s:property value="lastname"/>
</body>
</html>
```